# Spring MVC3 resources are loading including requestMapping Value in the context

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following configuration and I am not writing down other default configuration here

Spring-servlet.xml

> /WEB-INF/views/
>             
>             
>                 .jsp
>
> ```
>   <!-- Handle efficient GET requests for resources -->
> <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />
> <mvc:annotation-driven />
> ```

Controller Class

> ```
> @Controller     
> public class TablesController {
>
>
>
>   @Autowired
>   private ReferenceTableService referenceTableService;
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/tables/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>   public String ShowTables(ModelMap map,
>           @RequestParam(value = "tn", required = false) String tableName) {
>
>
>       return "tables";
>   }
> ```

jsp file

```
 <html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <head> <!-- Font Awesome  CSS -->
 <link href="resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head> <body>  Test </body> </html>
```

When I try to load locally:

http://localhost:9081/myapp/tables/edit

getting following error with static files under resources: You can see tables is added into the context

000000aa PageNotFound  W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/**tables**/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'application'

If I change requestmapping from **/tables/edit** to **/tables**, then resources are loading perfectly.

Following is the folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to fix this by adding contextpath to the css file as shown below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<link href="resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

to

`<link href="/myapp/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

`/myapp` means it will retrieve `css` in root path, without this it will do that in relative path.

Comment: Now, it is forming url with out application context [myapp]. http://localhost:9081/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css